# What is a "Maildir" in the context of git?

Tags: git, maildir

In the documentation for [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am), it mentions a "Maildir". However, when I search the rest of the Git documentation for what a "Maildir" is I don't find anything. My gut feel is that this is some general, non-git concept that I should already be familiar with (or, at the very least, the Git docs assume as much).

Can someone briefly explain what a "Maildir" is, at least within the context of `git am`, and optionally provide some more detailed reading material?

Comment: It's a [directory and file naming scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) for email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"git am" can apply patches that were emailed to you. The patches can be generated using [format-patch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch). When you receive patch emails, they can be stored as a single text file [mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) or each email stored as a separate file in a directory [mdir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir).

Comment: The mdir link is really what I was looking for. Thank you for that. It's a shame because I was hoping mdir could simply be a path to a directory containing a collection of `000*.patch` files (0001.patch, 0002.patch, etc).